# Окошко с аватарами

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

Вы знаете, как можно сделать окошко (как в ВК типа Друзья, Друзья-онлайн)

Ну то есть,  где там отображается 6 ав и под ними имена, я короче сделал НТМL структуру, которая в ВК и в голову ничего не лезет, как можно это создать. Кто знает, подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя проблемы с отображением аватарок в рядок, то либо

```
 float:left,
```

либо

```
display:inline-block
```

В общем случае, делается как-то так, ну и чтобы текст отображался под картинкой - размещаешь картинку в div, и, туда-же, текст (имя, фамилия, ник или чето в этом духе) в, например, еще один див либо абзац

Если у тебя проблема именно с серверной логикой - правильно сформируй вопрос. В любом случае для подсчета и вывода пользователей онлайн необходима сессия в БД.

Comment: он-лайн мне не надо) 
это я как пример написал

Answer (score 0):

У тебя есть таблица друзья. если делать по простому, то пусть в таблице есть столбец active с true и false, пусть если пользователь взаимодействует с БД каждый раз устанавливается значение true, но по итечении 5 минут если действий нет то ставится false, примерно так узнаешь кто он лайн) осталось только сделать запрос к друзьям и посмотреть кто он лайн. конечно все правильно делается через сессии. ну а там уже для формы напишешь ajax скрипт который делает get запрос к серверу, а тот ему отдает друзей он-лайн в json'e с аватаркой и ником. пусть скрипт каждую минуту дергает друзей. как-то так

Comment: паходу я чет не так понял =\\ да и то что я описал слишком ресурсоемкое...